# Where to check for session and trigger login

Tags: zend-framework2

I am starting a Zend Framework 2 project and I am a little stuck on something simple. I need to trigger the user to get redirected to a login page if they are not logged in using a session variable being present.

My question is, where is the best place to put a function to check to see if the user is logged in and if not send them to an authentication controller to start the login process? Since it needs to be checked all the time, where should it go?

Thanks!

Comment: Check how ZfcUser has realized the stuff. Zend\Authentication is the key to victory here. Start with authentication first and after that, go see about the authorization (dont allow other routes aside login when user is not logged in)

Answer (score 1):

In `Controller` you can write like this,

This will be trigged on each time it enters Controller before going any other `Action`

```
public function init()
{
    if (!(Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity())) { // if user session not exists
        //Redirect to login page
    } 

}
```

Comment: You would need to do that in every controller?